# Anular método do Angular Material Design

Tags: angular, material-design, componentes

Tenho um menu do angular material design que quando é aberto ele foca o primeiro item do menu, gostaria de remover esse método.

Eu vi no site do angular material que este método possui os seguintes atributos:

```
Methods
focusFirstItem
Focus the first item in the menu.

Parameters
origin

FocusOrigin = 'program' 
Action from which the focus originated. Used to set the correct styling.
```

Como eu posso anular esse método? Devo criar esse método no meu component.ts?

tentei algo como

```
focusFirstItem(origin){
 return false
}
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo de menu que foca no primeiro item? https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview, esse aqui exibe a lista sem selecionar nenhum

Comment: Já estou usando esse, mas o primeiro item vem com uma borda azul, provavelmente causado pela chamada deste método "focusFirstItem"

Comment: não deveria vir com a borda azul, pois não é o comportamento apresentado na documentação. Podes editar a pergunta com o seu cenário de código?